# OpenCV - How to copy part of an image to another with a mask?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to copy part of an image to another one based on a mask. But the result becomes white in all the mask pixels.

```c
Mat img = imread("a CV_8UC3 RGB image");
Mat mask = imread("the mask image which is a CV_8UC1");

Mat img_masked;
img.copyTo(img_masked, mask);

imshow("img_masked", img_masked);

cvWaitKey(1);
```

Here are examples of the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the original pixels of the **img** in the result but only in the location of **mask** pixels.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: According to opencv documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a626fe5f96d02525e2604d2ad46dd574f) the way you do it is correct. This seems like a bug in opencv. However, you should check a couple of things: do image's size match with the mask? Perhaps the `copyTo` assumes that mask must have the same number of channels as the original image - which is why output is kinda UB.

Comment: @ALX23z yes the sizes are the same. But even when both `img` and `mask` are `CV_8UC1` it doesn't work.

Comment: which opencv version do you use? You should post it to them as an official bug report. Let em' fix it. Hmm... when I think about I had another opencv algorithm that didn't work that well with a mask - had some boundary issues - but it was something complicated unlike copyTo.

Comment: Yes, I should. The version is 3.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways of doing this, depending on the data `type` of your `mats`.

The first one involves converting your images to grayscale. Since you didn't provide your inputs, I saved your screenshots as `RGB` `png` images and processed them this way:

```
//Read input image and mask (as RGB images):
cv::Mat imageInput = cv::imread( "C://opencvImages//road01.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR );
cv::Mat imageMask = cv::imread( "C://opencvImages//roadMask.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR );

//Convert images to grayscale:
cv::cvtColor( imageInput, imageInput, CV_RGB2GRAY );
cv::cvtColor( imageMask, imageMask, CV_RGB2GRAY );

//Prepare the masked image:
cv::Mat maskedImage;

//Use an AND operation to mask the original image:
cv::bitwise_and( imageInput, imageMask, maskedImage );

cv::imshow( "maskedImage [gray]", maskedImage );
```

As you see, I'm using a `bitwise and` to mask everything with a value of `0` in your original mask.

Here's another approach, assuming your input is an `BGR` (24-bit) image and your mask a binary (8-bit) image. You just basically `split` the `BGR` mat into three individual channels, mask them, and `merge` them back into a `BGR` matrix:

```
//BGR spliting:
std::vector<cv::Mat> bgrChannels(3);
cv::split( colorInput, bgrChannels );

//Mask every channel:
cv::bitwise_and( bgrChannels[0], imageMask, bgrChannels[0] ); //B
cv::bitwise_and( bgrChannels[1], imageMask, bgrChannels[1] ); //G
cv::bitwise_and( bgrChannels[2], imageMask, bgrChannels[2] ); //R

//Merge back the channels
cv::merge( bgrChannels, maskedImage );

cv::imshow( "maskedImage [color]", maskedImage );
```

Both solutions produce the same result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. I still don't understand why `copyTo` doesn't work with the mask, but good to know there is fast alternative.